# How to only alert when boolean is false (AND/OR set variable with javascript in Construct 2)

Tags: javascript, cordova, variables, construct-2

I am building an iOS-game in "[Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/construct2)" and trying to use the Phonegap-plugin "[Headset detection](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/714)" to alert if a Headset is not plugged in.

I am able to create an alert-box (true/falls) to tell if the user has plugged in a headset via this:

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function(detected) {alert(detected)})">headphone detected?</button>
```

But I am new to javascript, and would like to know:

How do I:

- Only alert if the detection is FALSE?
  OR (even better):
- Let the above boolean variable set another variable inside Construct 2? (That way I can make other dependancies in my game design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use unobtrusive event listeners, as opposed to inline JS:

```
<button id="headphone">headphone detected?</button>

function detectHeadphones(){
  window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function(detected){
    if(!detected){
      //No headphone detected
      alert("No headphone detected");

      // Set your variables here
    }
  })
};

var headphoneButton = document.getElementById("headphoneButton");
headphoneButton.addEventListener('click', detectHeadphones);
```

Then you can check detected for a falsey value thus: `if(!detected){` and set whichever variables you need within the callback. These variables will need to have been defined in a way that they are in scope at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this doesn't work inside Construct 2, as I am only able to controll what happens after the <button onclick="

Comment: Then just move everything into the inline event handler: `<button onclick="window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function(detected) {if(!detected){ alert("No headphone detected"); // Set your variables here }})">headphone detected?</button>`

Comment: I just have an "execute javascript"-option in Construct 2. And this is what I put in it (but it doesn't work): "window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function(detected){if(!detected){ alert('No headphone detected'); // Set your variables here }})"

Comment: Note: Other javascript execute commands (from Phonegap) works, like f.ex: "navigator.notification.vibrate(2500);"

Comment: is there an error in the syntax? Because this command gives me a dialogue: "window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function(detected) {alert(detected)})"

Comment: You need to remove the comment, this is causing the rest of the line to be ignored: `window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function(detected){if(!detected){ alert('No headphone detected');}});`

Comment: Good stuff. Glad we got there in the end :)